# Delayed job failed during capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job, activeadmin, thinking-sphinx

I'm using ActiveAdmin, capistrano to deploy, thinkng_sphinx to search and delayed_job to automatically run reindex for ts after adding new record.

Part from my deploy.rb

```
before 'deploy:update_code', 'thinking_sphinx:stop'
after 'deploy:update',  'thinking_sphinx:index', 'thinking_sphinx:start'

after 'deploy:finalize_update', 'sphinx:symlink_indexes', "delayed_job:stop", "delayed_job:start"
```

The problem is when running this command during deploy

```
 executing "RAILS_ENV=production /.../current/script/delayed_job stop"
```

I got

```
/.../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
Expected /.../releases/20120804075838/app/admin/users.rb to define Users (LoadError)
from /.../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
```

...

Here is app/admin/users.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register ::User do
  index do   
    column :name
column "E-mail", :email
 end
end
```

I tried to rename app/admin/users.rb to app/admin/user.rb - nothing

But if I run just from server command line:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop
```

all works fine

From my Gemfile

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'thinking-sphinx'
gem 'ts-delayed-delta', :require => 'thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta'
```

thinking-sphinx (2.0.12)
ts-delayed-delta (1.1.2)
delayed_job (3.0.3)
delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2)
activeadmin (0.4.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your deploy.rb.

```
require "delayed/recipes"
```

delayed recipes uses rails_env variable

```
set :rails_env,   "production"

# Delayed Job  
after "deploy:stop",    "delayed_job:stop"  
after "deploy:start",   "delayed_job:start"  
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart" 
after "deploy:update_code", "delayed_job:restart"

namespace :delayed_job do

desc "Stop the delayed_job process"
task :stop, :roles => :app do
  run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job -e #{rails_env} stop"
end

desc "Start the delayed_job process"
task :start, :roles => :app do
  run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job -e #{rails_env} start"
end

desc "Restart the delayed_job process"
task :restart, :roles => :app do
  run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job -e #{rails_env} restart"
end
end
```

Comment: yeah, the problem was in my "start" task definition.
It was `run "#{current_path}/script/delayed_job -e #{rails_env} start"` instead of cd to app dir and run script after, as you mentioned `run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job -e #{rails_env} start"`